# Обработка нажатия на FloatingActionButton

Tags: android

Есть код, который реализует FloatingActionButton.

```
public class FloatingActionButton extends View {

final static OvershootInterpolator overshootInterpolator = new OvershootInterpolator();
final static AccelerateInterpolator accelerateInterpolator = new AccelerateInterpolator();

Context context;
Paint mButtonPaint;
Paint mDrawablePaint;
Bitmap mBitmap;
boolean mHidden = false;

public FloatingActionButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    init(Color.WHITE);
}

public void setFloatingActionButtonColor(int FloatingActionButtonColor) {
    init(FloatingActionButtonColor);
}

public void setFloatingActionButtonDrawable(Drawable FloatingActionButtonDrawable) {
    mBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) FloatingActionButtonDrawable).getBitmap();
    invalidate();
}

public void init(int FloatingActionButtonColor) {
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);

    mButtonPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mButtonPaint.setColor(FloatingActionButtonColor);
    mButtonPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    mButtonPaint.setShadowLayer(10.0f, 0.0f, 3.5f, Color.argb(100, 0, 0, 0));
    mDrawablePaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    invalidate();
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    setClickable(true);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, (float) (getWidth() / 2.6), mButtonPaint);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, (getWidth() - mBitmap.getWidth()) / 2,
            (getHeight() - mBitmap.getHeight()) / 2, mDrawablePaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        setAlpha(1.0f);
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        setAlpha(0.6f);
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void hideFloatingActionButton() {
    if (!mHidden) {
        ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 1, 0);
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 1, 0);
        AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
        animSetXY.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
        animSetXY.setInterpolator(accelerateInterpolator);
        animSetXY.setDuration(100);
        animSetXY.start();
        mHidden = true;
    }
}

public void showFloatingActionButton() {
    if (mHidden) {
        ObjectAnimator scaleX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleX", 0, 1);
        ObjectAnimator scaleY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(this, "scaleY", 0, 1);
        AnimatorSet animSetXY = new AnimatorSet();
        animSetXY.playTogether(scaleX, scaleY);
        animSetXY.setInterpolator(overshootInterpolator);
        animSetXY.setDuration(200);
        animSetXY.start();
        mHidden = false;
    }
}

public boolean isHidden() {
    return mHidden;
}

static public class Builder {
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams params;
    private final Activity activity;
    int gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT; // default bottom right
    Drawable drawable;
    int color = Color.WHITE;
    int size = 0;
    float scale = 0;

    public Builder(Activity context) {
        scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        size = convertToPixels(36, scale); // default size is 72dp by 72dp
        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
        params.gravity = gravity;

        this.activity = context;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the gravity for the FAB
     */
    public Builder withGravity(int gravity) {
        this.gravity = gravity;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the margins for the FAB in dp
     */
    public Builder withMargins(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
        params.setMargins(
                convertToPixels(left, scale),
                convertToPixels(top, scale),
                convertToPixels(right, scale),
                convertToPixels(bottom, scale));
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the FAB drawable
     */
    public Builder withDrawable(final Drawable drawable) {
        this.drawable = drawable;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the FAB color
     */
    public Builder withButtonColor(final int color) {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Sets the FAB size in dp
     */
    public Builder withButtonSize(int size) {
        size = convertToPixels(size, scale);
        params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(size, size);
        return this;
    }

    public FloatingActionButton create() {
        final FloatingActionButton button = new FloatingActionButton(activity);
        button.setFloatingActionButtonColor(this.color);
        button.setFloatingActionButtonDrawable(this.drawable);
        params.gravity = this.gravity;
        ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        root.addView(button, params);
        return button;
    }

    // The calculation (value * scale + 0.5f) is a widely used to convert to dps to pixel units
    // based on density scale
    // see developer.android.com (Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes)
    private int convertToPixels(int dp, float scale){
        return (int) (dp * scale + 0.5f) ;
    }
}
```

}

В активити я добавляю кнопку следующим образом:

```
FloatingActionButton fabButton = new FloatingActionButton.Builder(this)
            .withDrawable(getResources()
            .getDrawable(R.drawable.plus))
            .withButtonColor(Color.WHITE)
            .withGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM | Gravity.RIGHT)
            .withMargins(0, 0, 16, 16)
            .create();
```

Как мне обработать нажатие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как ваш кастомный виджет наследник `View`, то отрабатывать клики по нему нужно точно так же, как и для любого другого наследника `View` - через реализацию интерфейса `View.OnClicklListener`:

```
fabButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v) {
            // Action for clicked
            }
        });
```

Однако , гугл недавно сделала свою реализацию виджета [`FloatingActionButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/FloatingActionButton.html) , который входит в состав библиотеки поддержки `android.support:design`,с этого времени рекомендуется использовать именно его. [Пример использования](http://antonioleiva.com/floating-action-button/).